# SQL convert amount into word for each digit (including dollar, decimal, and comma)

Tags: sql, oracle, decimal, cpu-word

I am attempting to convert a large dollar amount into words via oracle SQL for each individual digit. For example: 
$555,555,555.55 = "dollar five five five comma five five five comma five five five period five five".

I tried the Julian Date version of converting numbers to words but it only goes up to the ten-thousand place, no larger.

Please help.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a whole bunch of `REPLACE`s.

Comment: While not exactly what you're after I found [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/convert-number-into-words-oracle-sql-query/) interesting `select to_char(to_date(28385,'j'),'jsp')`  it only works with whole numbers (no decimals) though and doesn't handle the currency or commas.  replace seems to be best answer thus far.

Comment: That method is the Julian Date I mentioned. It does not work with numbers as large as I need. But thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515267/converting-integer-value-from-a-db-column-to-text-in-oracle

Comment: The Julian Date version doesn't do what you wanted anyway - it would not convert "555" into "five five five", but something like "five hundred fifty-five".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested replace:

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(col, '$', 'dollar '
                                                                                                      ), ',', 'comma '
                                                                                              ), '0', 'zero '
. . .
```

Comment: Which, for production, I would recommend making a function for readability purposes.

Answer (score 1):

[Results Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcYob.png) Okay I may have my syntax wrong but it forced an odd column in my results here is my code:

```
    SELECT SUM (amount) AS amount,
   REPLACE (
      REPLACE (
         REPLACE (
            REPLACE (
               REPLACE (
                  REPLACE (
                     REPLACE (
                        REPLACE (
                           REPLACE (
                              REPLACE (
                                 REPLACE (
                                    REPLACE (SUM (amount),
                                             '$',
                                             'dollar '),
                                    ',',
                                    'comma '),
                                 '.',
                                 'period '),
                              '0',
                              'zero '),
                           '1',
                           'one '),
                        '2',
                        'two '),
                     '3',
                     'three '),
                  '4',
                  'four '),
               '5',
               'five '),
            '6',
            'six '),
         '7',
         'seven '),
      '8',
      'eight '),
   '9',
   'nine '
```

Comment: I had the syntax off by one replace. Thank you problem resolved.